# node2vec requires torch-cluster

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to use `Node2Vec` from PyG and I am encountering the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-27749832cd17> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Node2Vec(pygraph.edge_index, embedding_dim=128, walk_length=20,context_size=10, walks_per_node=10, num_negative_samples=1, p=1, q=1, sparse=True).to(device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch_geometric/nn/models/node2vec.py in __init__(self, edge_index, embedding_dim, walk_length, context_size, walks_per_node, p, q, num_negative_samples, num_nodes, sparse)
     53 
     54         if random_walk is None:
---> 55             raise ImportError('`Node2Vec` requires `torch-cluster`.')
     56 
     57         N = maybe_num_nodes(edge_index, num_nodes)

ImportError: `Node2Vec` requires `torch-cluster`.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've gone through the PyTorch Geo Documentation listed [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/models/node2vec.html)

The error is thrown in the following lines of code:

```
if random_walk is None:
            raise ImportError('`Node2Vec` requires `torch-cluster`.')
```

To combat this, I've imported `random_walk` similarly to how it is being done in the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/models/node2vec.html)

Here is my code:

```
import os
import torch
os.environ['TORCH'] = torch.__version__
print(torch.__version__)

!pip install -q torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
!pip install -q torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git

from torch_geometric.nn import Node2Vec
!pip install torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
import torch_cluster
random_walk = torch.ops.torch_cluster.random_walk
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
model = Node2Vec(pygraph.edge_index, embedding_dim=128, walk_length=20,context_size=10, walks_per_node=10, num_negative_samples=1, p=1, q=1, sparse=True).to(device)
```

**Note:** Was being run on Google Colab.

Comment: Hi Suhas! This is not a solution to your issue specifically, but if you want to run a fast Node2Vec, you may want to try [our implementation in GRAPE](https://github.com/AnacletoLAB/grape). I have just benchmarked it against the one in Pytorch Geometric, which I somehow managed to get it to run, and we are much faster (105 times on my MacBook, embedding the Cora graph). Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

The Node2Vec model requires the torch-cluster library, which is a part of PyTorch Geometric (PyG).

Install torch-cluster by running:

pip install torch-cluster

But due to its dependencies on specific versions of PyTorch and CUDA, it might be easier to install PyTorch Geometric and all its components using the provided installation command.

pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have torch_cluster, you just need to install the pyg_lib version for torch. The exact code needed will depend on the running version of torch on colabs. As of right now, it is 2.1.0, but you're welcome to just change the link as needed. The following code is intended for colabs as of 02/24.

```
!pip install torch_geometric

!pip install pyg_lib torch_scatter torch_sparse torch_cluster torch_spline_conv -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.1.0+cpu.html
```